# OS-X - Fly Mode won't respond to mouse movements

Tags: camera

I'm using the latest build of Blender (2.75a). When I use the fly mode function (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>) I am unable to control the view of the camera with the mouse. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling, but that didn't work. This function worked fine the other day, but now it won't work. Any help would be appreciated! Working in Blender hasn't been more convenient since I've been using Fly Mode.

I'm running Yosemite, and my mouse works with everything else but controlling the camera's direction of view in Fly Mode.

---

*Fixed! The menu bar above the timeline was placed too high for my mouse's movements to be read.*

Comment: Did you worked with the latest official build (2.75) also "the other day" when things were fine? I'm using Windows and fly mode is ok. What's your OS?

Comment: Thank you for responding. Yes, it worked when I was using the latest version. I'm running Yosemite.

Comment: Can you change the camera's position with the keyboard? And toggling the gravity?

Comment: Yes. no problems with either of those. Everything works in Fly Mode except for the movement of my mouse guiding the camera's view. Even the scroll function works (the speed change).

Comment: Oh I found the problem! The Menu Bar above the timeline that lists the options "View", "Select", "Add", and "Object" was set too high by default-- the fly mode wasn't reading my mouse movements because they were outside the menu's navigation. Thanks again, Carlo!

Comment: Great! I would suggest to put that comment, maybe with a screenshot, in an aswer and accept it, so everyone can see it clearly.

Comment: @Avispa If you really have figured it out that's great news! This is driving lots of people nuts right now. Please elaborate with more details. Do you mean the Operator Panel? What do you mean by "set too high"? Could you please provide a screen shot?

Comment: Hello, Mentalist! I'd be happy to share a screenshot, here: http://puu.sh/k2w08/7215f30ce6.png

Answer (score 2):

[image: Solution!]

The mouse's movements can't be read in Fly Mode when the menu is like the example in red.

For this to work I also have to hide the right side of the menu like

so: http://puu.sh/k2Bl3.png

Comment: Thanks! I'll play around with this and see if I can reproduce what you experienced.

Comment: I made an edit to the answer that was necessary for this to work. That's the last of it!

Comment: New info! See the edit I made to my answer under "Update". I think your feedback helped with getting this bug resolved.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is a bug, specific to Mac. Please see [the bug report](https://developer.blender.org/T45771) that has been filed. Basically fly mode used to work fine on Mac in previous versions and now it doesn't, or at least not all of the time. Seems it's intermittent and nobody has been able to figure out the cause yet. But if you chime in on the bug report page it will further validate the issue, and maybe there you can read what other people have observed and get some ideas for how it can be reproduced consistently. Once it can be reproduced consistently, devs can hopefully isolate the cause and get it fixed.

### Update:

The bug has been fixed! So if you download the latest build you should be good to go! Seems it was a problem with calculation of cursor location on Retina Display Macs. See the new comments in the bug report I linked to for details. Avispa, your workaround seems to evade the problem by readjusting the layout in a specific way - but if you actually want it to be fixed, [get the latest build.](https://builder.blender.org/)