# Fly mode - mouse navigation does not work (2.79/Ubuntu)

Tags: 3d-view, interface, navigation

I have a problem with the fly mode on ubuntu and Blender 2.79. Everything was working perfectly a few hours ago, and suddenly the navigation control is not responding at all. The forward and backward movements, acceleration and deceleration still work fine. Only the mouse no longer allows you to change the direction: the cursor moves freely and the small target that usually appears in the centre of the screen has disappeared.

I have reloaded the factory settings, reinstalled the software, but nothing to do... I also found a thread with the [same problem](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38147/os-x-fly-mode-wont-respond-to-mouse-movements), but unfortunately the solution doesn't work for me. Does anyone have a solution?

Thank you very much!